# Raspberry pi : Make RPI code Read and Write Protected

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

1) I am working on a project on Raspberry pi. Once I finished my all stuff, I want my SD card/code to be properly locked. so that no one is able to read and write code just like we locked other small microcontrollers(AVR/PIC).Please help to do that.
2) I am generating logs in my code using logging library, will I be able to write logs if my SD card/code is write/read protected.

My objective is no one be able to steal my code or make modifications to the code. What should I do to protect my code from stealing and make changes into the code?

Comment: You can not hide code like this when dealing with an interpreted language. The scripts need to have read access available to any user who will be executing the interpreter to process the file. To obscure it some, you could embed the Python interpreter within a C application and use it to absorb the Python code. There is no fool proof way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me on this if I'm wrong but python being interpreted in most common implementations, I don't believe you're going to be able to make it unreadable.

Assuming that you are running linux on your raspberry pi, you might be able to get the tiniest bit of security using chmod 100 on it, but I do not know enough to confirm or deny this for sure.

Comment: how do i  block any user to change the permissions of the file.

Comment: That will absolutely not work. Since Python is an interpreted language, the file *must* have read access in order to execute it.

Comment: obviously, yes. i thought more along the lines of only allowing the executing user (and su) to read the file, shouldn't that allow them to run the script? Again, I'm nowhere near a professional in linux and its permissions system so this might be completely wrong.